# Installed OpenJDK 15 but $JAVA_HOME still points to oracle JDK 11

Tags: java

I have several versions of JDK installed, most of them OpenJDK, but I did install oracle-JDK-11. I am using Xubuntu 20.04 and I don't remember how I installed JDK-11. I have removed and oracle JDK-11 files and folders I can find. I have used update-alternatives to switch to OpenJDK-15. I have run

```
export $JAVA_HOME #all of these are complete on my end
PATH =
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

and ran them pointing to OpenJDK-15.

Still though `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle`
I have looked through all of the profile files that I know to look for and everything seems to be pointing to OpendJDK-15 but the variable still points to oracle-11.

My system is still aware of java-11-oracle somehow and I just want it completely removed. I am about to start a Java course so that I can finally learn it, but I want to make sure my system is setup correctly before I start.

Edit- For context, I will print a few of my files in /etc/profile.d/
**jdk.csh**

```
  1 setenv J2SDKDIR /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
  2 setenv J2REDIR /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
  3 setenv PATH ${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-ora    cle/db/bin
  4 setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
  5 setenv DERBY_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/db
```

**jdk.sh**

```
  1 export J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
  2 export J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
  3 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracl    e/db/bin
  4 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
  5 export DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/db
```

**jdk_home.sh**

```
  1 export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. I needed to update ~/.bashrc
In that file I added
`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-15/"`

Comment: Yes, If you would like to create and keep that variable throughout different terminal sessions it makes sense to put it into the ~/.bashrc file which will be executed whenever you open a terminal. Otherwise it will get lost once you close your terminal. Did you btw find out how `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle` was set into the `JAVA_HOME` variable?

Answer (score 0):

this will help you:
1, readlink -f $(which java)
2, sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/*

for more: [follow these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)